# How can I preinstall modules in node-red container

Tags: docker, node-red

I would like all my added modules to be installed att startup. I have checked in my .config.json and packages.json files, but running the node-red container on a clean system (without node_modules), the modules does not show up in the modules palette.
Is there some way to install these dependenceis automatically? For instance run "npm install" before node-red service is started?
As of now, I need to attach to container, run "npm install" manually and restart container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build your own version of the container. How to do this is described in the [README.md](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker#building-custom-image) for the container.

e.g. a custom Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM nodered/node-red
RUN npm install node-red-contrib-flightaware
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add all of the pallet names in the [package.json](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/blob/master/package.json) and try to push it in the docker itself (I do not have any experience with docker containers), your pallet names should be under dependencies along with the version itself, all of this info is obtainable through [npmjs](https://npmjs.com) . After you transfer the file an `npm install` will be needed for all of the dependencies to be installed.